# slow Mongodb $near search with additional criteria

Tags: mongodb, geo

I have a collection, the data look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4e627655677c27cf24000000"),
    "gps" : {
        "lng" : 116.343079,
        "lat" : 40.034283
    },
    "lat" : 1351672296
}
```

And I build a compound index:

```
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "gps" : "2d",
        "lat" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "test.user",
    "name" : "gps__lat_1"
}
```

A pure $near query like below can be very fast ( < 20ms ):

```
>db.user.find({"gps":{"$near":{"lng":116.343079,"lat":40.034283}}}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "GeoSearchCursor",
    "nscanned" : 100,
    "nscannedObjects" : 100,
    "n" : 100,
    "millis" : 23,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "indexBounds" : {

    }
}
```

But the query with "lat" criteria is very slow ( 900ms+ ):

```
>db.user.find({"gps":{"$near":{"lng":116.343079,"lat":40.034283}},"lat":{"$gt":1351413167}}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "GeoSearchCursor",
    "nscanned" : 3,
    "nscannedObjects" : 3,
    "n" : 3,
    "millis" : 665,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "indexBounds" : {

    }
}
```

Can anybody explain this? Great thx!

Comment: could you provide your output from explain() so we can see why it's slow?

Comment: without seeing what explain() outputs it's hard to know with certainty what's going on.

Comment: Stackflow.com told me I must provide more context for the code, so I deleted them. Now I provide them by edit. By the way, I just found the query with hint({lat:1}) got wrong result, it doesn't work.

Comment: I try the same query again with { $maxDistance : 10 }, it works.

Comment: But it still can't explain a query become very slow with a additional criteria. Maybe Mongodb scan the collection to filter data before doing the geo search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my Mongodb up to 2.2.0, the problem disappeared.

```
127.0.0.1/test> db.user.find({gps:{$near:[116,40]},lat:{$gt:1351722342}}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 0,
    "nscannedObjects" : 0,
    "nscanned" : 0,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 0,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 0,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {

    },
    "server" : "zhangshenjiamatoMacBook-Air.local:27017"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the explain above, it doesn't look like the geoIndex is being used at all - also, it looks like the above query didn't return any results!

If your query is using the 2d index, the explain should contain:

> "cursor" : "GeoSearchCursor"

Can you check if upgrading to 2.2.0 really solved your issue? :)

Sundar